# How to send Skype messages to chat group

Tags: java, skype, skype4java

I use https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api but I can't get group chat id. When I do:

```
Chat[] allChats = Skype.getAllChats();
```

it only gets chats with one person.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
   Group[] allGroups = Skype.getContactList().getAllGroups();
   for (Group group : allGroups) {
       System.out.println(group.getId());
   }
```